# Flutter - How to list all images from Firebase Storage

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

I need to list all images from a specific directory in Firebase Storage.
This solution shows how listAll() works https://stackoverflow.com/a/58430817/13720706

But if I use this:

```
void getFirebaseImageFolder() {
    final StorageReference storageRef =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('Gallery').child('Images');
    storageRef.listAll().then((result) {
      print("result is $result");
    });
  }
```

I get a long string with many values:

```
result is {prefixes: {}, pageToken: null, items: {2020-06-2816:15:51.669533_250x250.jpg: {bucket: xxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com, path: /userStorage/xxxxxxxxxxx/k6ouUrjUhMXJjDButEtF/L8H5IVSVhUKPLaGFLBaK/3VfcLmjR8ojxzPCboM9U/thumbs/2020-06-2816:15:51.669533_250x250.jpg, name: 2020-06-2816:15:51.669533_250x250.jpg}, 2020-06-2816:14:31.223608_250x250.jpg: {bucket: xxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com, path: /userStorage/xxxxxxxxxxx/k6ouUrjUhMXJjDButEtF/L8H5IVSVhUKPLaGFLBaK/3VfcLmjR8ojxzPCboM9U/thumbs/2020-06-2816:14:31.223608_250x250.jpg, name: 2020-06-2816:14:31.223608_250x250.jpg}}}
```

So the question is how can I tap into this values? How can I get only the path of the images?

I tried this: *result.items.path*
But it does not recognize this command.

Somebody knows how to list the images?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to list URL of all photos from specific directory.

```
Future<void> listPhotos() async {
    firebase_storage.ListResult result = await firebase_storage
        .FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref().child('Gallery').child('Images').listAll();

    for (firebase_storage.Reference ref in result.items) {
     String url = await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref(ref.fullPath)
      .getDownloadURL();
        print(url);
    }
  }
```

You can follow [this link](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage/) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function :

```
get firebaseStorage => FirebaseStorage.instance;

class StorageMethods extends GetxService {
  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    getBackgrounds();
  }

  List backgrounds = [].obs;
  var loader = false.obs;
  Future<void> getBackgrounds() async {
    loader.value = true;
    ListResult result =
        await firebaseStorage.ref().child('format_backgrounds/').listAll();
    loader.value = false;
    for (Reference ref in result.items) {
      String url = await firebaseStorage.ref(ref.fullPath).getDownloadURL();
      debugPrint("==========>" + url);
      backgrounds.add(url);
    }
  }
}
```

And then you can use that list containing all your images from firebase storage.